# Azure mobile service to sent push notification to specific IOS user

Tags: c#, ios, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am able to send push notification to all the devices with below code

```
   ApplePushMessage message = new ApplePushMessage("Item : "+ item.Name+ " Saved", System.TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

        try
        {
                var result = await Services.Push.SendAsync(message);
                Services.Log.Info(result.State.ToString());

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Services.Log.Error(ex.Message, null, "Push.SendAsync Error");
        }
```

I need to sent to specific user using device token.

I found the code with node.js. But with .net i am not able to send only to the specific user.

```
// Get the ID of the logged-in user.
var userId = user.userId;

function insert(item, user, request) {
    request.execute();
    setTimeout(function() {
        push.apns.send(userId, {
            alert: "Alert: " + item.text,
            payload: {
                "Hey, a new item arrived: '" + item.text + "'"
            }
        });
    }, 2500);
}
```

Is there any equivalent code method in Dotnet. Or can i have to user tags instead of device token?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the tag is the better approach, i believe. We use that and it works perfectly.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx - guidance

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3 - some code.

---

If that is the helpful answer, please mark it as a helpful or as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I am using custom Registration (not using Aad or login providers) , Can i have to create tag for each user while registration?

Comment: Absolutely. When user is doing the registration, you execute the SubscribeToTag("push___userlogin") (pseudocode). I would propose you to implement the settings as well (for user to being able to unsubscribe :-) and, please, do not forget the logic that will refresh everything needed for push (channel, etc). In our app, we have the settings pane where you can switch the setting (for example, "weekly news") and after that the app subscribe the user to the tag (not so specific as yours, but the approach is the same). And your tags will be saved with the device registration, so it is very handy.